# Parsing an algebraic function or expression from a string

Tags: c++, string, parsing, c++17

Let's say that I will have an algebraic function or expression that is in the form of a `std::string`. Either a function or a class constructor would accept this string as a parameter.

```
void function( const std::string& function ) { /* ... */ }

class Foo {
    explicit Foo( const std::string& function ) { /* ... */ }
};
```

Then let's say I have a function that will parse this string and then convert it into a `std::function` where my current function signature looks like this:

```
template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
void parseStringFunc( const std::string& funcStr, std::function<Ret(Args...)>& func ) {
     /*....*/
 }
```

Now comes the question in mind as it has to do with parsing the string. I have two choices to work from and I wanted to know which one would be the preferred choice as a lookup table.

- I could have a `std::vector<char> operators { '+', '-', '*', '/', '=' }`

  - The same above but for numbers or digits [0-9]
  - and for letters [a-z] and [A-Z] where this would be tedious.
- Or I could make it simpler and have just a `std::string`:

  - `std::string operators { "+-*/=" };`
  - `std::string numbers{ "0123456789" };`
  - `std::string letters{ "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" };`

I'm wondering which would be the preferred choice above to use for a look up table to compare the individual characters within the `funcStr` that will be parsed to be converted into a `std::function`.

Comment: This seems to focus on the trivial.  I'd expect you to be interested in how do the parsing itself.   See my SO answer on how to write a parser.  With that in hand, you can decide which of these makes sense to you.   See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336769/120163